# Node JS Express robots.txt disallows only /search but Google Search Console reports "indexed, though blocked by robots.txt" for other URLs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, seo

I'm currently working on an application built with Express. I have tried to implement `robots.txt`.

This is what I have right now:

```
app.use(
    '/robots.txt', 
    function (req, res) {
        res.type('text/plain');
        res.send("User-agent: *\nAllow: /\nDisallow: /search")
     );
 });
```

While I am able to see the results in the website, google search is giving me  the warning:

> Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to implement the `robots.txt` file?

Comment: If you view your robots.txt file, does it look like you expect?

Comment: You can remove `Allow: /\n` from your `robots.txt` file.  By default everything is allowed.  That directive is redundant at best and at worst may confuse some bots because only `Disallow` directives are part of the official `robots.txt` specification.  (Google understands them, so that shouldn't be the problem with the error in search console.)

Comment: What is an example URL that Google thinks is blocked by robots.txt?